# Converting String to Integer error

Tags: java

i translate my code and i am facing an error. Here is my code:

```
 private boolean checkPlace(Coordinate c){
    return "0".equals(matrix[String.valueOf((char) c.getx())][String.valueOf((char) c.gety())]);
}
```

The error is:   Incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

Matrix is a 2D array, getx returns an integer and gety returns an integer.
Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: `matrix[String][String]` doesn't work in Java. You need `matrix[int][int]`.

Comment: The indexes of the array are integers. Don't convert c.getx and c.gety to strings.

Comment: My array contains integers and one string. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How did you define your array? It can contain either strings or ints, not both.

Comment: I defined all the elements of the array as Strings

Comment: @samevans You're talking about the *values* of the array. The *indexes* of the array must be `int` values. Try `matrix[c.getx()][c.gety()]`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error you're getting is because you're trying to reach your Matrix[x][y] with strings instead of integars ie: Matrix["x"]["y"].

You need to convert to string after you receive the coordinates value for the equals(String, String) function.

Hope that helps!

Comment: i need to define my array as string because i said before there is one string character besides all the integers. Do you know how can i run this?

Comment: @samevans It doesn't matter what type of array it is. An array of *any* type can only be indexed by an integer.